# VBA Enter key event in IE not working in another machine

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have one text box in my web page and I entered one number on it. After that I want to execute “Enter” key press event. How to do that?

I tried:

1. Sendkey option (it's not working properly, looking for some good alternate option for that)
2. I also tried following option suggest by someone. In this case this work fine in one system however when I tried the same code in different machine with same IE version same Excel version, it’s not working.

The code:

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Const VK_ENTER = &HD

Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer

Function ENT()
    keybd_event VK_ENTER, 1, 0, 0
End Function
```

VBA code I used to input number in that text box:

```
.document.getElementById("filteredListForm:wfmtAllTaskList:wfmtAllTaskList_columns_2:2:_filterInput").Value = number
```

** after this code I what to execute enter key event in this text bow.

HTML code for that Text box:

```
<input id="filteredListForm:wfmtAllTaskList:wfmtAllTaskList_columns_2:2:_filterInput"
class="mdw_columnFilter" type="text" placeholder="Project ID"
onblur="hideFilterInput(this);" onkeydown="submitOnEnter(event, this.form);"
value="" name="filteredListForm:wfmtAllTaskList:wfmtAllTaskList_columns_2:2:_filterInput">
```

Comment: Look at FireEvent, however looks like it's just calling the submit of the form, so get the elements form, and call the submit yourself.

Comment: double check what submitOnEnter does, if you can, I think it will just check for enter key rather than entering text.

Answer (score 0):

Not, an answer, backup for comment, using HTML Object Library

```
Public Function x(i As Control)

Dim d As HTMLDocument
Dim f As MSHTML.HTMLFormElement
Dim e As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement

Set e = d.getElementById("x")
Set f = e.form
f.submit

End Function
```